# Update SQLite does not change python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

My code runs through but the update does not stick:

```
conn.execute('''UPDATE COMBINATIONS \
SET METRIC = COMBINATIONS.FREQ_EVER / help.DOCS_EVER \
FROM (SELECT DOCS_EVER, TERM FROM TERMS) AS help WHERE COMBINATIONS.SEARCH = help.TERM;''')
conn.commit()
```

So when I do the following:

```
test = conn.execute('''SELECT METRIC FROM COMBINATIONS WHERE SEARCH = "and" AND SUGGESTED = "in"''')
for row in test:
    print(row)
```

.. I get only my old default values. Anyone an idea why and how to fix it?

I tried the following to check whether I get results from the SELECT version of my statement, and I do get plenty of results:

```
test = conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM COMBINATIONS, (SELECT DOCS_EVER, TERM FROM TERMS) AS help WHERE COMBINATIONS.SEARCH = help.TERM;''')
for row in test:
     print(row)
```

I am using the sqlite3 package in python. It's SQLite version 3.32.2.

Comment: `WHERE SEARCH = "and" AND SUGGESTED = "in"` is a filter that does not exist in the UPDATE statement. Post sample data to clarify your problem.

Comment: "and" and "in" are two words that are present in my table in the SEARCH/SUGGESTED columns. Rows containing these words should have been updated with my UPDATE statement earlier. However, if I execute the test with this SELECT statement, they are still the same before and after. Does this clarify?